# Linux program for timeline(s) with own time units

Tags: linux, opensuse, timeline

I'm searching for a timeline program. But not something "normal", but a program where I can define my own time units, for example a Year with 13 Months or even units which change depending on some aspects.  And, like it's written in the headline, it should run under Linux (Suse).